# Jquery Mobile changePage load sites without to switch the header

Tags: jquery-mobile, header, slide

at this moment, when I am calling changePage() with slide transition, then the whole page is sliding and the header as well. Is it possible, that on changePage the header is static and only the buttons and title of the header is changing, but the header is staing static as an native app.

I mean, I have read somewhere, that the pages in JQM are loaderd by Ajax. But on my App I see how the pages are switching complete and this looks very weak.

Is it possible to make the switch somehow, as if the header is static and only the content is swithched?

Comment: Well here is a page, where this effect is possible: http://m.ondho.com/ How do they make it?

Comment: Easy, an example you showed us is not a jQM web application. You have to understand how jQM works to be able to understand how to solve an problem. Header and Footer are integral part of a jQM page and when you change a page you are also changing header and footer. I will write you an solution but it is not an easy one.

Comment: Hey Gajotres, yes the example is not for JQM, but I see, that JQM will never switch the pages so fast. Do you have example for Jquery only, where I can switch only the content and hold the header and footer fix?

Comment: Look at my answer below. Carouse is best thing you can do. I can tell you it has much better transition effects then normal page changing. Carousel will give you functionality from your example, but if your app is not going to be very big use destroysound example instead.

Comment: Hi I don't know the destroysound. I need to read about it. But look at my link: http://jsfiddle.net/Gf4uL/ Here is your answer, that it is possible to make the header static and change only the buttons on it ;-)

Comment: You are still changing 2 pages and each page has its header. destroysound is a guy who gave you first answer.

Comment: Aaa ok! Yes I am changing 2 pages, but the header is not moving and overlaping the old one. This is the trick ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with changePage, but you could just load in new content to the content div, like this:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="main_page">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1 id="page_title">My Title Here</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <div id="page_data">
            <button id="changepage">ChangePage</button>
          <h3>Some stuff</h3>
            <input type="text" value="sometext" /><br />
          <ul data-role="listview">
           <li>Some other stuff</li>
          </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Then when you want to change the page:

```
$("#page_title").html("New page title!");
$("#page_data").html("<h3>my awesome markup</h3>"); // this could come from ajax'ing
$("#page_data").trigger('create');
```

Keep in mind any buttons you have on the title bar will need to be hidden and shown as well. You can transition the new content in by having multiple content divs and using `$.animate` or `$.fadeIn`.

Edit: Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9PVC/2/ (now with fadeOut and fadeIn).

Comment: Ok I understand now what I need to do. Is there a similar solution like this example: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/11/04/full-height-app-layouts-navigation-and-history/ but realized in jQuery?

Comment: I thing in the example, what I have posted, the transition is great! Very fast and smooth especially on Iphone 4.